# Text length in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Please tell me the difference between `test.length` and `[test length]`?

Which is more usefull for iOS developement?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between self.foo=nil and \[self setFoo:nil\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511748/whats-the-difference-between-self-foo-nil-and-self-setfoonil)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No difference in meaning, they both access `length` property.

Their only difference is syntactic.

Check [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html) about sending a message to an object

Answer (score 2):

`test.length` is just a convenience syntax introduced in Objective C 2.0. The two expressions you list are totally equivalent and a matter of preference more than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same. Sometimes it may (!) be better to use one or the other for readability of your code.